# Help regarding translation of a text from Padma Purana 7.3.47b-51

Tags: karma, dharma, sin, translation

The following quote is from Padma Purana, Kriyāyogasāra-Khaṇḍa, Chapter 3 - The Story of King Manobhadra, verses 47b-51:

https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-padma-purana/d/doc365844.html

> 47b-51. These two large-armed ones, are really (men) of meritorious vows and a great heart. If there is any bad act seen among all acts, it is not giving a present to a brāhmaṇa, after picking it on their own. O king, due to that act only, these two went to hell. The giver who after picking a gift does not give it to a brāhmaṇa, goes to a fierce hell causing fear to all beings. The giver would not remember the gift; the receiver does not ask for it. Both live in hell as long as the moon and the sun are (in the sky). Therefore, O lord, these two, snatching the wealth of a brāhmaṇa, are great sinners.

The meaning is not clear to me. Can someone help? What was the sin of the two candalas exactly - not giving charity to brahmanas, stealing from brahmanas or something else?

Answer (score 1):

[This text](https://play.google.com/books/reader?id=_UoIAAAAQAAJ&hl=en&pg=GBS.PA68) has a summary of the same story and conveys the meaning better:

> This Purana relates that a king, Manobhadra, having grown old and weak, resolved upon dividing his kingdom between his two sons. He therefore convoked a council of his ministers, when, of a sudden, a vulture and his mate flew into the hall, to the surprise of the whole assembly. Questioned about the purpose of their visit, they replied that, having witnessed the evil luck of the two princes in a former birth, they now came to rejoice in their happiness. The king's curiosity having been roused, the male vulture then said, that in the age called Dwapara, the two princes had been two men of low caste, called Gara and Sangara, and when dead, were brought before Yama, the judge of the dead, who sentenced them to be thrown into a fearful hell. Their lives had indeed been faultless; no sin had been committed by them, but **whenever they gave alms they did not offer them to a Brahmana, and thus robbing the latter of the property which otherwise would have come to him, they became candidates for hell**.